# Phoenix JDBC TImestamp Column issues

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am working on Hbase database and using apache Phoenix to access Hbase using normal SQL queries.

I have two columns in table which holds the current UTC timestamp in varchar and Date. after loading some data and when I query back Hbase I am getting strange results for event timestamp column which is of Date type.

```
Event UTC (Date) :2017-01-13 16:36:59.0
Event UTC (varchar):2017-01-13 21:36:59
```

above two values should be identical but for each record when querying back Event UTC ( Date) column giving me wrong result i.e exactly 5 hours behind. 
I dont know from where this problem is coming .I am not saving any Timezone info and I am aware that Java Util or SQL timestamp doesnt store any time zone info, But really confused with the result set data when running a query. Please Help me in resolving this issue

Comment: 1. check your phoenix server time and your hbase server time.

2. their is a possible chance of mismatch in time between phoenix server and hbase server

3. you can use ntp (network time protocol) for synchronizing time zones

Comment: also restart your jvms after doing the ntp sync.  you can end up with offsets you don't intend. also you can check the time on hbase

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because of the client's local time zone.

From [official docs](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#timestamp_type)

Timestamp type:

> the internal representation is based on a number of milliseconds since the epoch (which is based on a time in GMT), while java.sql.Timestamp will format timestamps based on the client's local time zone.